# Xamarin OpenGL GLSurfaceView constructor throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, opengl-es, xamarin.android, live-wallpaper

I am trying to implement android LiveWallpaper with Xamarin opengl.
But when i activate LiveWallpaper, GLSurfaceView throws null reference exception in constructor.

Error line: 
 base(context) when calling the base constructor of GLSurfaceView.

Error detail: 
 Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 
'void android.view.SurfaceHolder.addCallback(android.view.SurfaceHolder$Callback)' 
on a null object reference

```
[Service(Label = "@string/ApplicationName", Permission = "android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" })]
[MetaData("android.service.wallpaper", Resource = "@layout/MyLiveWallpaper")]
public class OpenGLWallpaperService : WallpaperService
{
    public override Engine OnCreateEngine()
    {
        return new OpenGLWallpaperEngine(this);
    }

    public class OpenGLWallpaperEngine : Engine
    {
        private readonly OpenGLWallpaperService _serviceInstance;

        public OpenGLWallpaperView GLWallpaperView { get; set; }

        public OpenGLWallpaperEngine(OpenGLWallpaperService serviceInstance)
            : base(serviceInstance)
        {
            _serviceInstance = serviceInstance;
        }

        public override void OnCreate(ISurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
        {
            base.OnCreate(surfaceHolder);
            GLWallpaperView = new OpenGLWallpaperView(this, _serviceInstance, surfaceHolder);
        }
    }
}

public class OpenGLWallpaperView : GLSurfaceView
{
    private readonly OpenGLWallpaperService.OpenGLWallpaperEngine _engineInstance;

    public override ISurfaceHolder Holder { get; }

    public OpenGLWallpaperView(OpenGLWallpaperService.OpenGLWallpaperEngine engineInstance, 
        Context context, ISurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) 
        : base(context)
    {
        _engineInstance = engineInstance;
        Holder = surfaceHolder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing wrong with override to Holder. Holder should't be overridden.

Cancel this line and related things:
public override ISurfaceHolder Holder { get; }